# Genymotion Lollipop Doesn't Support Multiple Profiles?

Tags: android, genymotion

If you go to a Genymotion virtual device's settings, there's no user icon!

Are multiple profiles / users supported in Genymotion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to enable it via adb.

Try the following commands:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o rw,remount /system
echo fw.max_users=4 >> /system/build.prop
echo fw.show_multiuserui=true >> /system/build.prop
exit
```

Restart genymotion after that.  If the users menu doesn't appear in setting immediately after restart you will want to add at least one user manually through adb.

```
adb shell
su
pm create-user <username>
exit
```

Restart after adding the user.  The users option under settings should be visible now.